# Debian 7.9 gnome or kde don't work on sparc server

Tags: debian, sparc

I have a Sparc server with Debian 7.9 I tried to install gnome or KDE with these commands but it doesn't work:

```
root@LABS://# apt-get install gnome  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done  
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have  
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable  
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created  
or been moved out of Incoming.  
The following information may help to resolve the situation:  
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
 gnome : Depends: gnome-core (= 1:3.4+7+deb7u1) but it is not going to be installed  
**E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.**  

root@LABS://# apt-get install kde  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done  
**E: Unable to locate package kde**
```